# Access callbacks in JS class in VueJS template

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, vue.js, fine-uploader

Hi everyone i have the following problem, i have a class written in ES6 Javascript which you can see [here](https://codeshare.io/an4lRE). It is essentially an implementation of FineUploader, now my problem is that FineUploader has several **callbacks**

```
  callbacks: {
    onAutoRetry: (id, name, attemptNumber) => {
      this.$emit('autoretry', {id, name, attemptNumber})
    },
    ...
```

and these should be defined in that **constructor** and can execute different actions that i would like to take place in my Vue Template. (as you can see i used to have `$emits` and everything)
Is there any way that i can bind these callbacks to methods on a Vue Template of mine? Or would i have to create a whole component for this FineUploader implementation?

Thank you in advance for your help

Comment: If you don't have components, where are you emitting to?

Comment: hi @retrograde bad example in this case, but the problem is in this case FineUploader calls these callbacks internally right? And what i want is to hook into these from my Vue components and know the best way to do it.
I kinda figured out i can import my non-vue class into a component and simply use lodash.merge on it's constructor and pass in options in the class constructor to "override" these callbacks with my own when i actually instantiate the class and that works fine.
But i wonder if there is a better way that i'm missing